# Best practice (GRPC communication) architecture Microservice (List vs Loop)

Tags: architecture, microservices, grpc

I want to know what do you think about this two ways to get user :

I have a Grpc service "GetUser" and "GetUsers"

Model of User

```
{
userName : string
email: string
firstName: string
LastName: string
}
```

I have userIds list (between 1 to 5000 Ids).

What is the more efficient :

```
Call Grpc => GetUsers(ids[]) 
Or loop Call Grpc => GetUser(id)
```

NOTE : anyway i will have one access to the DB by user

Answer (score 0):

If you do a unary `GetUser` RPC in a loop, there will be [additional framing](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/PROTOCOL-HTTP2.md) per call, meaning more bytes on the wire. So, viewed from the perspective bytes transmitted/received, `GetUsers` is more "efficient".

However, a `GetUsers` RPC requires you to hold the whole dataset in memory at once. Since you apparently only need 5000 IDs, this may not be an issue for you. But for larger datasets, this can become a real issue.

If both the memory and the additional framing are unacceptable to you, you can look at a [streaming RPC](https://grpc.io/docs/what-is-grpc/core-concepts/#service-definition) like:

```
rpc GetUser(stream GetUserRequest) returns (stream GetUserResponse);
```